# Is it possible to change the text color of a search result?

Tags: css, search-results, display-template

Anyone ever customize the text color of a search result based on the type of content? It came up in a recent conversation and I thought I'd pose the question. I'm thinking display templates could solve the problem, but wanted others' input before I work on a poc.

Comment: What version of SharePoint? The approach depends on the version. It's way easier in 2013.

Comment: 2013.  I'm thinking display templates could solve the problem, but wanted others' input before I work on a poc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Display Template for the content type and change the title style the way others have indicated.

1. Create a copy of an existing Display Template
2. Rename the file and edit the file in your favorite HTML editor
3. Inside the file rename the Title attribute to something you will recognize later
4. Edit the Title styling (or add a new attribute)
5. Save the file back to SharePoint
6. Create a new Result Type rule to display your template for the content type
7. Test, Test, Test.

Refer to this post for the specifics of each step: http://www.ableblue.com/blog/archive/2013/06/05/introduction-to-sharepoint-2013-display-templates/
And this one for debugging: http://www.ableblue.com/blog/archive/2014/03/01/create-a-diagnostic-display-template/

Comment: Thanks, Matthew.  This confirms what I was hoping and gives me the direction I need.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of changing the Search in SharePoint . 
1. Add a Content Editor Web Part on the page and added the following CSS in its HTML Source Editor.

```
<style>
.srch-results {
background-color:red;
}</stlye>
```

Refer : https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/Brand-SharePoint-Search-Results-What-you-thought-you-were-staying-vanilla.aspx

2.Change the XSLT :The out of the box search results, the kewords are marked as bold, but it can be easily marked with background color by changing the XSLT. 
To highlight the search results with different background color follow these simple steps:
1) Edit search results page
2) Modify the search core results webpart (Click on Modify Shared webpart menu)
3) Under search core results tool pane, click "XSL Editor" button. Copy the xsl and save it in a text file

Comment: Sure, but I want to change the color of the text instead of the background and I don't want to do it for all search results.  I want to do it for only certain search results based on their content types.

Answer (score 0):

You may go ahead by targeting the div elements and then specifying CSS for them. 
Something like -

```
.ms-srch-item-summary {
     color:blue;
 }
```

Otherwise, you might be better of by creating your own display templates to cater to your requirements and changing what and all is required.

Comment: Sure, but I don't want to do it for all search results. I want to do it for only certain search results based on their content types.  I'm thinking display templates could solve the problem, but wanted others' input before I work on a poc.